# How to make revenue $0 for months prior to decrease in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following data:

| client_id | balance_month | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $400 |
| 100000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |
| 100000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $200 |
| 100000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $300 |
| 200000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $99 |
| 200000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |
| 200000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |
| 200000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |

What is the most efficient way to make all prior months prior to the most recent month with a decrease in balance have $0 such that:

| client_id | balance_month | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $400 |
| 100000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $100 |
| 100000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 100000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | September 1,2021 12:00 AM | $99 |
| 200000000 | August 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | July 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |
| 200000000 | June 1,2021 12:00 AM | $0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LAG() window function to check if there is a decrease in the balance and MAX() window function to check when the last decrease happenned:

```
SELECT client_id, balance_month, 
       CASE 
         WHEN balance_month < 
              MAX(CASE WHEN prev_balance > balance THEN balance_month END) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id) 
           THEN 0 
         ELSE balance 
       END balance
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(balance, 1, balance) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY balance_month) prev_balance
  FROM tablename
) t  
ORDER BY client_id, balance_month DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0b9fcc08915c3fb8563c35acc7d9f336).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to get the decrease, then a window function to get the date:

```
select t.*,
       (case when balance_date > first_decrease_balance_date
             then 0
             else balance
        end) as new_balance
from (select t.*,
             min(case when prev_balance > balance then balance_date end) over (partition by client) as first_decrease_balance_date
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(balance) over (partition by client_id order by balance_month) as prev_balance
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```